# PHP Dynamically create and update multiple rows with forms and multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I need to update table rows via  a form.  Sometimes there will be a single row but sometimes multiple, therefore I need the forms to post multidimensional arrays that can easily be looped through and updated in the (Wordpress) database.

I thought the below is how you do it but the $_POST array isnt correct.  What do I need to change?

```
    //function to disaply form fields for each row
    public function make_form($results) {
    
        $html_fields = '';
        $count = 1;

        foreach($results as $result) {
            if($count != 1){
                $html_fields .= '<h4>Row: ' . $count . '</h4>';
            }
            
            foreach($result as $field_name => $field_value) {

                if ($field_name !='ID'){
                    $html_fields .= '<p><label for="' . $field_name . '">' . $field_name . '</label><br />';
                    $html_fields .= '<input type="text" value="' . $field_value .'" id="' . $field_name . '" name="' . $field_name . '[' . $result->ID . ']"></p>';
                }
            }   
            $count ++;
        }
    
        return $html_fields;
    } 
    
    //function to update database with form data 
    public function update_row() {
        global $wpdb;
    
        $wpdb->show_errors = true;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mytable';
            
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
    
        foreach($_POST as $id => $values){
            $results = $wpdb->update($table_name, $values, array( 'ID' => $id ));
        }
    }
```

The array prints out as this:

```
Array (
    [REF] => Array
        (
            [648] => D10902B-SE
        )

    [QC] => Array
        (
            [648] => 1
        )

    [QCT] => Array
        (
            [648] => EA
        )

    [update] => Update )
```

When I need something more like this:

```
Array
    (
        [648] => Array
            (
                [REF] => D10902B-SE
                [QC] => 1
                [QCT] => EA
            )
    
        [555] => Array
            (
                [REF] => TESTREF
                [QC] => 2
                [QCT] => EAFFFFF
            )
    )
```

I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Your desired array is not possible, you can't have multiple same keys with different values. (I mean, you _can_ but the previous values will be overwritten)

Comment: Ok, so how do I do it?  I just want to identify which fields are for what row.  The Array key ideally would be the ID of the row but yes I get thats not possible now.

Comment: I have changed the array format.

Comment: You could just iterate over `$_POST` and create the output you want

Comment: Or change the order in your `name` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the order of how you name the input as mentioned in the comment

```
$html_fields .= '<input type="text" value="' . $field_value .'" id="' . $field_name . '" name="' . $result->ID . '[' . $field_name . ']"></p>';
```

Comment: I tried that but the array comes back as empty and in the source the input looks like this: <input type="text" value="" id="QC" name="[QC]">  maybe its something to do with the array key being an integer?

Comment: its means $result->ID doesnt have a value, make sure it has a value before using it